# Laravel testing JSON responses

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

This returns true

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/api/languages');
$this->assertEquals(["es", "ca", "en"], $response->response->getData());
```

But this one false

```
$this->json('POST', '/api/languages')->seeJson(["es", "ca", "en"]);
```

The error message:

```
tests\ApiLanguageTest::testApiLanguage
Unable to find JSON fragment [["ca"]] within [["ca","en","es"]].
Failed asserting that false is true.
/home/vagrant/www/lumen-api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:283
/home/vagrant/www/lumen-api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:208
/home/vagrant/www/lumen-api/tests/ApiLanguageTest.php:21
```

I tried `seeJson` before like this:

```
$this->json('POST', '/api/version', ['name' => 'Foo'])
         ->seeJson(["result" => true,"message" => "Bar"]);
```

And worked great, can't understand why it fails in languages

Comment: Could you edit your question and add what you're API call returns? Keep in mind that seeJson (If I remember correctly) requires a full match not a partial match of the response

Comment: @Ken Thanks for your comment. The problem was my API returns an array without key => values on the first level so it wasn't a testable JSON for seeJson